# Excel: Passing Cell Value to VBA SQL Statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, interbase

I have searched forever and cannot find a solution that works. Most likely because of ignorance.

The database that I am querying is Interbase so the SQL syntax might be different than what I'm used to. When I add the following line to my SQL statement I get an error "Run time error: 1004" SQL Syntax Error.

```
"AND    p.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE %" & Worksheets("Page1").Range("H9").Value & "%"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are more likely to get help if you avoid expressions such as "I have searched forever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about interbase but I suspect you need to surround the text-expression with apostrophes:

```
"AND    p.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%" & Worksheets("Page1").Range("H9").Value & "%'"
```

Remove the unnecessary spaces as well:

```
"AND p.DISPLAY_NAME LIKE '%" & Worksheets("Page1").Range("H9").Value & "%'"
```